# terraform init unable to fetch modules coming from terraform providers mirror when using third party modules

Tags: terraform

I am using this instruction to prefetch my providers :

```
terraform providers mirror  /usr/share/terraform/providers
```

The `mirrors.tf` looks like this :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.27"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "~>1.13"
    }
    okta = {
      source  = "okta/okta"
      version = "~> 3.22"
    }
```

Afterwards, I locate myself in a terraform folder where I intend to init the okta module that should have been prefetch before like this :

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "my-organization"

    workspaces {
      name = "my-workspace"
    }
  }
}

provider "okta"  {
  org_name    = "org_name"
  base_url    = "base_url"
  client_id   = "client_id"
  scopes      = [ "scope1" ]
  private_key = "private_key"
}
```

When doing the same with hashicorp modules it works fine. But with okta `terraform init` ends up like :

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/okta...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/okta: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/okta was not found in any of the search locations
│
│   - /usr/share/terraform/providers
```

When looking into the /usr/share/terraform/providers , I find that  terraform has an okta/okta folder and an hashicorp/kubernetes.

How could I tell terraform to look for okta provider in the okta/okta and not the hashicorp/okta ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the module location in the `source` as by default it will search `registry.terraform.io`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mirrors.tf` file you showed contains a set of [provider requirements](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements) which includes the reference to the `okta/okta` provider which the mirror command requested for you.

In order to use those same providers in other Terraform modules, you should place the same `required_providers` block inside the `terraform` block of each module that will use the `okta/okta` provider. Terraform will then understand that within that module you intend the short name "okta" to mean `okta/okta`, rather than the default of `hashicorp/okta`.

Terraform assumes providers in the `hashicorp/` namespace by default for backward compatibility for modules that were originally written for Terraform v0.12 or earlier, which didn't yet support automatic installation of third-party providers like this one. However, if you are using current Terraform versions (v1.1 is current at the time I'm writing this, but this is true all the way back to v0.13) then you should typically include a `required_providers` block in every module you write in order to be explicit about which providers the module depends on, unless you need your module to [remain compatible with Terraform v0.12](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements#v0-12-compatible-provider-requirements).